# Using YouTubeIt gem to get videos from YouTube

Tags: ruby-on-rails, youtube-api

I am using the YouTubeIt gem, trying to get the first 6 videos that get returned from this query:

```
client=YouTubeIt::Client.new
vidoes = client.videos_by(:most_viewed, region: "RU")
```

I don't know how to get any data out of what gets returned from that

I can however get the title and URL of a video if just 1 is returned from a query:

```
video = client.video_by("UID of video here")

video.title #=> title gets returned

video.media_content[0].url #=> URL of video gets returned
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What happens when you do `puts videos.inspect`?

Comment: It returns the same stuff but when I call video.inspect.class it returns a "string" instead of YouTubeIt::Search::Response

It looks like it's returning a bunch of Nokogiri::XML::Elements, how would I get the first 6 of the same element in plain text?

Comment: can you post the results of videos.inspect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go...

```
client   = YouTubeIt::Client.new
response = client.videos_by(:most_viewed, region: "RU")

response.videos[0..5].each do |video|
  puts "#{video.title}: #{video.media_content[0].url}"
end
```

Comment: Thanks Brian! I forgot to get back to you with the results because I ended up figuring it out. This was for rails rumble this past weekend!

Comment: Ah, I hope it went well! I saw your x-post on reddit as well :-)

Comment: It did! Thank you so much for your prompt response Brian!